# removing top records from ng-repeat and append again based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat which loads large amount data. I'm using `limitto` filter to load more records which appends 10 records each time when we scroll to bottom of the page. How to remove top 10 records whenever new 10 records are added. Any quick solution will be appreciated.

```
 <ul class="lists">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:totalDisplayed">
     <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </li>
     <li>
     <button ng-click='loadMore()'>Load More</button>
     </li>

</ul>


    $rootScope.totalDisplayed = 5;
    $rootScope.load_more = function () {
        $rootScope.totalDisplayed += 10;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 
    $scope.initial = 0;
    var limitStep = 10;
    $scope.limit = limitStep;
    $scope.incrementLimit = function() {
     $scope.initial = $scope.limit;
        $scope.limit += limitStep;
    };
   
    $scope.decrementLimit = function(){
     $scope.limit -= limitStep;
        $scope.initial -= 10;
};
   
    $scope.items = [{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'abc'},{'name':'bcd'},{'name':'bcd'},{'name':'bcd'},{'name':'bcd'},{'name':'bcd'},{'name':'bcd'},{'name':'bcd'},{'name':'bcd'},{'name':'bcd'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'},{'name':'cde'}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul class="lists">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: limit track by $index" ng-if="$index < limit && $index > initial">
     <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul> 
<button ng-click='decrementLimit()' ng-disabled="initial===0">Load Previous</button>
<button ng-click='incrementLimit()' ng-disabled="limit===items.length-1">Load Next</button>        
</div>
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: nice solution but what if i want to load older records.

Comment: but it will load all the records, i just want to load only old 10 records and hide 10 newer just like virtual scroll

Answer (score 0):

One of the feasible way is ng-if:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:totalDisplayed">
  <span ng-if="yourConditions()">{{item.name}}</span>
</li>

$rootScope.yourCondition = function(){
   //calculate if it is "skipped"
}
```